# Angular 6 with Openlayers drawLine

Tags: angular6, openlayers

I want to draw a routing line from Land of Canaan to Waipu but After I compile the line become like this,

[image]

What I expect is like this,

[image]

My code:

```
routing.forEach((obj, index) => {
  const line_point = [];
  obj.waypoints.forEach((pos, i) => {
    const lng = Number(pos.lon);
    const lat = Number(pos.lat);

    line_point.push(ol.proj.fromLonLat([lng, lat]));

  });

  const routeLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [new ol.Feature({
      geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(line_point, 'XY'),
      name: 'Line'
    })]
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#bc0000',
      width: 2
    })
  })
});
  routeLayer.setZIndex(55);
  this.mapLayer.push(routeLayer);
  this.map.addLayer(routeLayer);
});
```

May I know what happened to this and how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I had updated my route path code on top.

Answer (score 2):

One of your LineString ist crossing the antimeridian (180° W/E). A solution is to split the LineString at the antimeridian.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is have issues. You have to consider split the line in as many chunks as be needed. As you did not provided the code, I am able only to include cases in conceptual way.

Your array variable could be an array of arrays with all line chunks needed to draw.

> `line_point`

Includes a draw with border cases:

- Line a-b is similar to your case with two chunks.
- Line c-d is other case with two chunks.
- Line e-f is an complex case where there is three chunks.

[image: Discontinues lines cases]

The dotten light green line represent the union between the chunks